# Rails: 404 page not found error for the below url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have made a website using ruby on rails.

I have defined below routes in my routes.rb file.

```
  get "/WhatsOnTV/Program/:programmename"          => "whatsonredirect#index"
  get "/Whatsontv/Program/:programmename"          => "whatsonredirect#index"
  get "/whatsontv/program/:programmename"          =>  "whatsonredirect#index"
```

But i am getting 404 page for `/WhatsOnTV/Program/Rakhwala_No._1.aspx` request.Dont know what went wrong. Please help.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with dot in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is the problem with the url:-

**By default dynamic segments don’t accept dots – this is because the dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a dot within a dynamic segment add a constraint which overrides this – for example :id => /[^/]+/ allows anything except a slash.**

That would for example be:

```
get "/:user/contributions" => 'users#contributions', :constraints => { :user => /[^\/]+/ }
```

Also you can get help from the following link:-

http://avdi.org/devblog/2010/06/18/rails-3-resource-routes-with-dots-or-how-to-make-a-ruby-developer-go-a-little-bit-insane/